# Artifacts when using solidify on curves

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

When i apply the solidify modifier to curves (created by importing a svg file), it creates some weird artifacts. Any idea on how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a logo that I had imported. What fixed it for me was this process. (Blender 2.90.1)

- Note, sometimes it is quicker to join similar curves, like text, by selecting them and then selecting Object -> Join *

1.) In object mode, select the imported curve.
2.) Select Object -> Convert To -> Mesh from Curve/Meta/Surf/Text.
3.) Tab into Edit mode.
4.) Select all points using A.
5.) Press X and select Limited Dissolve.
6.) Tab back to Object mode and add your solidify modifier.

This method works very well for curves with few points. I have had some imports that still had some artifacts after using this method which required manipulation of the vertices to solve the problem (deleting, moving, etc.) but was really trial and error after using the method described above.

Hope it helps!